# The best approach to sum tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

i am new in Haskell programming, I got a database which store student data and mark of exam like below

```
type Student = String
type MarkProject = Float
type MarkMidSem = Float
type MarkFinal = Float

type Database = [(Student, MarkProject, MarkMidSem, MarkFinal)]

exampleBase :: Database
exampleBase = [("Barry", 23, 24, 43), 
           ("Wayne", 22, 20, 49), 
           ("Ivan", 21, 25, 48),
           ("Alli", 24, 24, 48),
           ("Martial", 22, 25, 49)]
```

i want to create a function to find a student total marks for exam.

TotalMarks = MarkProject + MarkMidSem + MarkFinal

i had tried couple times to do his function but failed. I also cerate a function to insert student , markProject, markmidsem and markfinal like:

```
totalMark :: Student -> MarkProject -> MarkMidSem -> MarkFinal -> Float
```

Can anyone to guide me how to complete the function for totalMarks? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make an extra type, for the data tuple, and make Database use that type, after that just create a function that takes the tuple, pattern match it and sum what you need.

```
type Student = String
type MarkProject = Float
type MarkMidSem = Float
type MarkFinal = Float

type StudentData = (Student, MarkProject, MarkMidSem, MarkFinal)
type Database = [StudentData]

exampleBase :: Database
exampleBase = [("Barry", 23, 24, 43), 
           ("Wayne", 22, 20, 49), 
           ("Ivan", 21, 25, 48),
           ("Alli", 24, 24, 48),
           ("Martial", 22, 25, 49)]

totalMark::StudentData -> Float
totalMark (n, mp, mms, mf) = mp + mms + mf
```

Comment: May i ask you an extra question? i need to create an another function to use value return from totalMark for find student grade. Can you give me some hint? Thank!

Comment: @noleavename, what is it exactly studen grade?

Comment: I was typo, is subject grade  like based on the mark,  70 ~ 100 = A ,60 ~ 69 = B ,50 ~ 59 = C.

Comment: Hi, i have done this function while waiting your reply.
i use
`gradeStudent::StudentData -> String
gradeStudent (n, mp, mms, mf)
  | a >= 0 && a < 29 = "D"
  | a >= 30 && a < 49 = "E"
  | a >= 50 && a < 59 = "C"
  | a >= 60 && a < 69 = "B"
  | a >= 70 && a < 100 = "A"
  where a = totalMark(n, mp, mms, mf)`
Thank you for helping me sort out this!

Comment: @noleavename, yep that function looks perfect, sorry for the late answer, i was on a bus trip..

Comment: is ok, without your helping in the first question, i won't be done the second question. Have a nice day!